# Unexpected gaps in timestamps when using Pandas.DataFrame.GroupBy on a string column and with Pandas.Grouper for DatetimeIndex

Tags: pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

Hello StackOverFlow friends!

I am attempting to calculate an aggregate sum with Pandas.DataFrame.groupby over two keys, one of which is a column of type String and the other is a time-series index (DatetimeIndex for the observation timestamps).

I used the following code and experienced the unexpected result of measurement_end_time being discontinuous with intervals between time groups exceeding the expected 1 hour at the times when there were no data points for a specific server in the DataFrame (read further for an example that explains why I expect a different result):

```
df.groupby(by=['server_fqdn', pd.Grouper(freq='1H')]).total_test_count.sum()

server_fqdn                       measurement_end_time     
server1.company.com               2021-05-01 00:00:00+00:00     80
                                  2021-05-01 04:00:00+00:00    130
                                  2021-05-01 07:00:00+00:00      3
                                  2021-05-01 08:00:00+00:00     87
                                  2021-05-01 11:00:00+00:00      3
                                  2021-05-01 12:00:00+00:00    129
                                  2021-05-01 16:00:00+00:00     90
                                  2021-05-01 20:00:00+00:00    137
                                  2021-05-01 22:00:00+00:00      3
                                  2021-05-02 00:00:00+00:00    136
                                  2021-05-02 04:00:00+00:00     92
                                  2021-05-02 08:00:00+00:00     95
                                  2021-05-02 12:00:00+00:00     68
                                  2021-05-02 16:00:00+00:00    103
                                  2021-05-02 18:00:00+00:00      3
                                  2021-05-02 20:00:00+00:00    120
                                  2021-05-03 00:00:00+00:00     92
 
server2.company.com               2021-05-01 00:00:00+00:00    452
                                  2021-05-01 01:00:00+00:00      7
                                  2021-05-01 03:00:00+00:00     10
                                  2021-05-01 04:00:00+00:00    446
                                  2021-05-01 07:00:00+00:00      7
                                  2021-05-01 08:00:00+00:00    495
                                  2021-05-01 10:00:00+00:00      3
                                  2021-05-01 11:00:00+00:00      6
                                  2021-05-01 12:00:00+00:00    423
                                  2021-05-01 13:00:00+00:00     15
                                  2021-05-01 14:00:00+00:00     14
                                  2021-05-01 15:00:00+00:00     11
                                  2021-05-01 16:00:00+00:00    422
                                  2021-05-01 17:00:00+00:00     14
                                  2021-05-01 18:00:00+00:00      4
                                  2021-05-01 19:00:00+00:00     13
                                  2021-05-01 20:00:00+00:00    447
                                  2021-05-01 21:00:00+00:00      7
                                  2021-05-01 22:00:00+00:00      8
                                  2021-05-01 23:00:00+00:00      7
                                  2021-05-02 00:00:00+00:00    420
                                  2021-05-02 01:00:00+00:00      6

Name: total_test_count, Length: 145776, dtype: int64
```

My expectation is for the measurement_end_time timestamp intervals to be completed with the missing hours so that measurement_end_time is contiguous with 1 hour intervals through all 24 hours of the day and with zero values for the sum of the missing timestamp intervals as follows:

```
server_fqdn                       measurement_end_time     
server1.company.com               2021-05-01 00:00:00+00:00     80
                                  2021-05-01 01:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 02:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 03:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 04:00:00+00:00    130
                                  2021-05-01 05:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 06:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 07:00:00+00:00      3
                                  2021-05-01 08:00:00+00:00     87
                                  2021-05-01 09:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 10:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 11:00:00+00:00      3
                                  2021-05-01 12:00:00+00:00    129
                                  2021-05-01 13:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 14:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 15:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 16:00:00+00:00     90
                                  2021-05-01 17:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 18:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 19:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 20:00:00+00:00    137
                                  2021-05-01 21:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 22:00:00+00:00      3
                                  2021-05-01 23:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-02 00:00:00+00:00    136
                                  2021-05-02 01:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-02 02:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-02 03:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-02 04:00:00+00:00     92
                                  2021-05-02 05:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-02 06:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-02 07:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-02 08:00:00+00:00     95
                                                              ... 
                                  2021-05-02 20:00:00+00:00    120
                                  2021-05-02 21:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-02 22:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-02 23:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-03 00:00:00+00:00     92
 
server2.company.com               2021-05-01 00:00:00+00:00    452
                                  2021-05-01 01:00:00+00:00      7
                                  2021-05-01 02:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 03:00:00+00:00     10
                                  2021-05-01 04:00:00+00:00    446
                                  2021-05-01 05:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 06:00:00+00:00      0
                                  2021-05-01 07:00:00+00:00      7
                                  2021-05-01 08:00:00+00:00    495
                                                              ... 

Name: total_test_count, Length: 145776, dtype: int64
```

Note that I expect the result above given that the following command that aggregates only by the DatetimeIndex yields the expected results for the measurement_end_time correctly:

```
df.loc[df.server_fqdn == 'server1.company.com'].groupby(by=pd.Grouper(freq='1H')).total_test_count.sum()
measurement_end_time
2021-05-01 00:00:00+00:00     80
2021-05-01 01:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 02:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 03:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 04:00:00+00:00    130
2021-05-01 05:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 06:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 07:00:00+00:00      3
2021-05-01 08:00:00+00:00     87
2021-05-01 09:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 10:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 11:00:00+00:00      3
2021-05-01 12:00:00+00:00    129
2021-05-01 13:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 14:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 15:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 16:00:00+00:00     90
2021-05-01 17:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 18:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 19:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 20:00:00+00:00    137
2021-05-01 21:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-01 22:00:00+00:00      3
2021-05-01 23:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-02 00:00:00+00:00    136
2021-05-02 01:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-02 02:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-02 03:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-02 04:00:00+00:00     92
2021-05-02 05:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-02 06:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-02 07:00:00+00:00      0
2021-05-02 08:00:00+00:00     95
```

I am hoping for an explanation for this unexpected outcome and a Python/Pandas solution that gets me the expected outcome as described.

Thanks in advance StackOverFlow Community!